# How can I supress this type error from Django create_user?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm getting the following type error from pylance:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

get_user_model().objects.create_user(**user_data)
#                        ^- Cannot access member "create_user" for type "BaseManager[Any]"
#                           Member "create_user" is unknown Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues

# User.objects.create_user(**user_data) # same error
# AbstractUser.objects.create_user(**user_data) # same error
```

For some reason it thinks `AbstractUser.objects` has a broader type `BaseManager[Any]` instead of `UserManager`, even though `AbstractUser` defines `objects = UserManager()`.

The code works without errors when tested.

Does anyone know how I can supress or get rid of this sort of type error?

Comment: If you are using `django-stubs` and Mypy >=1.5.0, you may want to follow: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/1648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define `objects` in your User model you should give it a type like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    
   objects: UserManager = UserManager()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# import of `UserManager`

user_manager: UserManager = get_user_model().objects

user_manager.create_user(**user_data)
```

Comment: No luck `Expression of type "BaseManager[Any]" cannot be assigned to declared type "UserManager[Unknown]" /  "BaseManager[Any]" is incompatible with 
 UserManager[Unknown]"`

Comment: Wait, why couldn't you use just `User.objects`?

Comment: `User.objects.create_user` also reports type error `Member "create_user" is unknown` :/

Comment: Are you sure that you imported the `User` that actually has `create_user`?